# Wordpress wallpaper Plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

hii I am making a site related to entertainment which also has Movies Wallpapers category
where i want that i can add new Movie wallpapers in single post and People can View and download them easily ?
So it will be very difficult to check all Available Plugins
So i need suggestions which plugin is better for my Idea Site ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is use NextGen Gallery and then in the picture description provide a download link to the wall paper or the original picture file.

You can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: but it don't give code for post?
how to get code for adding wallpaprs in post not in page ?
THANks

Comment: well sorry i got that option in New Post
well Thanks For Answering :)

Comment: Not a problem. Anytime. :)

Comment: @realcoder if this answer solved your problem, then you should **accept** it.

Answer (score 2):

I would say custom post templates would be the way to go with this.

Here's a tutorial I used successfully: http://www.vooshthemes.com/blog/wordpress-tip/create-a-professional-portfolio-using-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any particular need for a Plugin in order to implement this functionality. The core WordPress media management would handle it just fine, including uploading/attaching your WallPaper image files, adding description/metadata, and inserting the image in the post.

Answer (score -2):

I have a wonderful plugin for creating wallpaper sites using WordPress that can automatically fetch wallpapers and post or you can upload bulk wallpapers as you like. It automatically resizes images so you don't have to worry. Also the package comes with a premium wordpress theme for wallpaper sites. You can check at http://plixpress.com/

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.